# Как вывести цифровое значение

Tags: wordpress

Есть дополнительное поле (код ниже), в котором выводится цифровое значение, например  27.09.2012. как вывести цифровое значение только после первой точки например так 27.09

Как можно обернуть код ниже или может как то через регулярные выражения?

```
< ?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'version', true) ? >
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```
$str = '27.09.2012';

echo substr($str, strpos($str, '.') + 1);  //09.2012
```